# angularjs checkbox not updating model on update

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update checkbox value, when I try to check or uncheck the checkbox it doesn't update the ng-model value it persis

```
<tr height="44" ng-repeat="res in resources">
    <td>{{res.project}}</td>
    <td>{{res.resource}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" placeholder="Resource Weightage" ng-model="res.alloc" ></td>
    <td>
        <input  ng-checked="res.add==1 || isAllSelected" type="checkbox" checklist-value="res.add" checklist-model="res.add">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ng-checked="res.edit==1 || isAllSelected" type="checkbox" checklist-value="res.edit" checklist-model="res.edit">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ng-checked="res.delete==1 || isAllSelected"  type="checkbox" checklist-value="res.delete" checklist-model="res.delete" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <input  ng-checked="res.view==1 || isAllSelected" type="checkbox"  checklist-value="res.view" checklist-model="res.view">
    </td>
</tr>
```

[Screen Shot of Request is here](http://prntscr.com/bmx1zq)

Comment: can you please throw some light on how the checklist is binded in scope

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bmx9f3

Comment: currently these are all checked and I just want to make some of them unchecked but when I try to uncheck it doesn't update the value rather it persist it's old value

Comment: a reference link..check if this helps https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs of `checklist` directive](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

It's necessary to set to `checklist-model` array that will contain values, but in the `checklist-value` it's necessary to put the value that will be pushed to the array.

in other words it should be like that

```
 <input type="checkbox"  checklist-value="'some value'" checklist-model="someTargetArray">
```

I suppose you should use simple checkbox with ng-model like

```
<input  type="checkbox"  ng-model="res.view">
```

Comment: I just used checklist-model in place of ng-model by reading some thread on stackoverflow but still it's not working

previously I was using simple checkbox with ng-model

Comment: @vicky92727
Then I can suppose that the problem in using `ng-checked`, according to docs on 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

`Sets the checked attribute on the element, if the expression inside ngChecked is truthy.

Note that this directive should not be used together with ngModel, as this can lead to unexpected behavior.`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming using [this](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) plugin. so according to the example in the link you need to pass value of your input bot in `checklist-value` and you don't need `ng-checked`.

Here i am assuming you want an `res` to contain an array like `['add','edit','delete','view']` when checkboxes are selected.

```
<tr height="44" ng-repeat="res in resources">
            <td>{{res.project}}</td>
            <td>{{res.resource}}</td>
            <td>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Resource Weightage" ng-model="res.alloc"></td>
            <td>
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="'add'" checklist-model="res">
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="'edit'" checklist-model="res">
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="'delete'" checklist-model="res" >
            </td>
            <td>
             <input type="checkbox" checklist-value="'view'" checklist-model="res">
            </td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

hey guys thanks for your support but unfortunately no solution worked for me rather I've tried another solution that's worked for me

in view

```
<input ng-true-value='1' ng-false-value="0"  ng-checked="res.add==1 || isAllSelected" value="1" ng-change="update($index,res,'a')" type="checkbox" ng-model="res.add">
```

and in controller

```
$scope.update = function(index,data,crud) {

    if (crud=="a") {
        $scope.resources[index].add = data.add;
    } else if (crud=="e") {
         $scope.resources[index].edit = data.edit;
    } else if (crud=="d") {
         $scope.resources[index].delete = data.delete;
    } else if (crud=="v") {
        $scope.resources[index].view = data.view;
    }

};
```

this solved my problem now I can get updated value of check boxes.